# Same APNS token returned by two different applications

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How can same APNS token be returned for two different applications installed using profiles created from two completely different apple enterprise accounts?

However the notifications are properly received by the respective applications! just curious to know how apple manages to map with correct device and the right application.

Comment: Need more information on how you have generated the token, can you share the piece of code you have written to read the Device Token from NSData.

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Received device token: %@",deviceToken];
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All apps on the same device get the same device token. Apple knows which app should receive the notification because the certificate you use to send the notification is unique for each app.

Comment: So APNS token need not be unique for every application on the same device? I haven't seen this scenario using development profiles! but only happens using distribution profiles! any more insight regarding this ?

Comment: I don't recall the tokens behaving different for development profiles, but it has been a while since I tested APNS in sandbox env. On sandbox env the device has a different token than on production, but it's still the same for all apps.

Comment: I don't agree, I have already tested and since iOS 7, two different apps, with different certificates get different tokens

Comment: @Jesuslg123 I know. This answer was written before iOS7.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like up to iOS 6, the token was the same for all apps on the same device, the way to difference them, it was the certificate.

From iOS 7+, the token is unique for each app and device. So every app on the same devices will get a different APNS token.